# Ruby On Rails f.checkbox hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I have a check box on a rails form like this:

```
      .columns.small-1
       = f.label :private
       = f.check_box :private
```

if the box is unchecked, the form sends correctly with one value passed.  If the box is checked the form sends the same field twice with one value as 0 and one as 1, which is causing the box to always show as unchecked" and have a value of 0. Been researching hidden fields in rails but not sure how to apply to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is a normal behavior. By default, `f.check_box` renders a hidden field with value 0. Right after that hidden field, it renders an input field of type "checkbox" with the value 1. The input field and hidden fields have the same name. When both of these values are sent to the server, the later value (checkbox) will overwrite a param value with that name. This should be done automatically for you, unless you are trying to parse the params manually.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what is the technical requirement behind this behavior?

Comment: @DavidGay because this way you get the unchecked-checkbox submitted, otherwise the unchecked value would never reach the server.